# Is there a way to multiply the two columns into a new column from the below query?

Tags: sql

```
 CASE
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 0.10
 AND ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 < 0.25 THEN ''1.0'' 
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 0.25
 AND ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 < 0.5 THEN ''1.0'' 
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 0.5
 AND ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 < 1.0 THEN ''1.0'' 
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 1.0
 AND ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 < 2.5 THEN ''0.75'' 
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 2.5
 AND ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 < 5.0 THEN ''0.5'' 
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 5.0
 AND ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 < 10.0 THEN ''0.25'' 
 WHEN ((la.occtotallimit + la.attachmentpoint)/2)/NULLIF(SUM(l.replacementvaluea+l.replacementvalueb+l.replacementvaluec+l.replacementvalued),0)*100 > 5.0 THEN ''0.0'' 
 ELSE ''1.0'' end as SRCC_RATIO,



 CASE
 WHEN la.attachmentpoint >= la.occtotallimit THEN la.occtotallimit*la.occparticipation
 ELSE (la.occtotallimit-la.attachmentpoint)*(la.occparticipation) end as Exposure
```

Want a new column that is SRCC_RATIO*Exposure

Comment: Use a _derived table_. (Or cte.)

Comment: Or `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your query with an outer query and do the math...

```sql
Select q1.*, 
       q1.SRCC_RATIO * q1.Exposure as NEW_MATH_COLUMN
From   ( ... your query code here ... ) q1
```